# Retrieving last message related to a specific status in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a table called Sessions containing PC:s downloading software.

[image]

I want to create a new column or a measure that shows which version of the software the PC is downloading or has downloaded recently.

Software version can be found in the message at the start of the download.

My measure currently looks like this but in visuals it filters out the rows where the status is not "Start"

```
Result = CALCULATE(MAX(Sessions[Message]),
ALLEXCEPT(Sessions, Sessions[PC]), Sessions[Status]="Start")
```

(There is also a  DateTime column in Sessions that can be used)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with a measure.
By using TOPN and filtering by dateTime i could return a single row.
By using MAXX on this row i got the correct SW

```
getLatestSW = 
VAR SINGLE_ROW= TOPN(1,, FILTER(Sessions, Sessions[Status]="Start"),
    Sessions[DateTime], DESC)
return MAXX(SINGLE_ROW,[Message])
```

This was also possible with LOOKUP.

```
getLatestSWLookUp = 
VAR LASTID = MAXX(FILTER(Sessions, Sessions[Status]="Start"),
    Sessions[dateTime])
return LOOKUPVALUE(Sessions[Message], SessionEvents[dateTime], LASTID)
```